# Cake PHP - new localization not appearing as option

Tags: php, cakephp, localization

We have a Cake app developed by contractors. It is set up for multiple languages (apparently). I can see the language subdirectories under /locale - however, if we add new translated .po files into, for example, the /LC_MESSAGE subdirectory for French (including default.po for that lang) the French language does not display in the language change dropdown.

I've checked the Cake docs, and while Cake seems to suggest the locale subdirectories are all two character names (eg. "fr" for French as per example above), the developers have set it up using "fra" instead. I am not sure if this is a problem, or just a sign of Cake's flexibility.

Another thing is that the working translation we do have (Spanish) shows in its folder duplicate .mo files as well as our original .po files. I have converted the default.po file to default.mo for the fra locale and uploaded that, cleared browser cache, and reloaded and still no French language becomes available in the language selector.

Ideally we want to be able to add and update new languages as they become available without turning to the developers every time (they allow spammers onto the host, unfortunately). Does the Cake app have to be rebaked each time we add a locale language? Do I need to delete cache files in the Cake app on the host to enable new languages? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> the /LC_MESSAGE subdirectory for French

The folder should `LC_MESSAGES`, plural.

> the developers have set it up using "fra" instead. I am not sure if this is a problem, or just a sign of Cake's flexibility.

3 letter language codes work too. Though I don't remember if it should be `fra` or `fre`.

> I have converted the default.po file to default.mo for the fra locale and uploaded that

Having .mo files is not strictly necessary. Cake can read .po files too.

> Does the Cake app have to be rebaked each time we add a locale language?

Unless the developer has done something really weird, no.

> Do I need to delete cache files in the Cake app on the host to enable new languages?

Yes. After adding a new language you need to clear application cache. For your case clear all files in `/app/tmp/persistent` folder.